# Combination with repetition, differences in calculation

Tags: c++, math, combinations

I have a small program. I have to calculate combination with repetition.
My code:

```
int factorial(int a){

    if (a<0)
    return 0;
    if (a==0 || a==1)
    return 1;
    return factorial(a-1)*a;
}
long int combinationWithRepetion(int n, int k){
    long int a,b,wyn=0;

    wyn=factorial(n+(k-1))/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-1));

    return wyn;
}
int main()
{
    int k,n=0;
    cout<<"Give n: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Give k: ";
    cin>>k;
    cout<<"combination With Repetion for n="<<n<<
    " k="<<k<<".\n Is equal to "<<combinationWithRepetion(n,k)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For n=9 and k=6 in Wolfram alfa I get 3003, but in this program the result is 44.

For me the code is fine.

Comment: who would you trust? Wolfram Alpha or your code?

Comment: @MitchWheat, his own code, obviously!

Comment: @MitchWheat but what you think about code, maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `n=9` and `k=6` you compute `factorial(14)` which is `87,178,291,200` which will overflow a 4-byte `int`. You need to use something like `long long` to get an 8-byte `int` if you want to use this formula.

There are better formulas for computing binomial coefficients which do not rely on computing the full factorials then doing the division. See [Binomial coefficient in programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_in_programming_languages), the direct method (rather than using recursion).

In C++ you can use:

```
int binomial(int N, int K) {
  if( K > N - K )
    K = N - K;
  int c = 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < K; ++i) {
    c *= (N - i);
    c /= (i + 1);
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: On a platform with 64-bit long longs, a one-line change to `long long factorial(long long a)` is sufficient to make it work.

Comment: @David Schwartz - That will work, but since factorial grows so fast it will overflow for `factorial(21)`, so I added the link to a better way to compute binomial coefficients without computing the factorials first.

Answer (score 0):

So you are calculating (n+k-1) choose k. Substiuting n=9,k=6, it is 14choose6(=3003). But 14! takes more than 36bits to represent, but your int only has 32 bits. A better implementation would be to simplify n!/((n-k)!*k!) to n*(n-1)*...*(n-k+1)/k!. Or you can use pascal triangle.